# How to Prevent unity attribute callback from running, such as [ PostProcessScene ] , [ RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod ] , etc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback, unity3d-mirror

currently I'm building a package that allows initialization before the awake() process of unity called (editor only).

to make that happen i create a script which have ScriptExecutionOrder -1 , and disabling all gameobject on scene start (awake). then starting process initialization such as loading data from server, database or etc, which can't run synchronously and takes a time. and when the initialization finished i reactivate all the object to previous state.

but there is a script that keeps running because of some callbacks from unity, such as
[ PostProcessScene ] , [ RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod ]
.
in my case i got the script from Mirror package, so i can't just delete the attribute

[image: PostProcessScene]

How, to prevent that attribute from called? or how to pause the callback attribute from unity?

Comment: I don't think you can

Comment: Why is specifically that script an issue anyway? It simply fetches NetworkIdentities in your scene and anyway is only called in the editor ...

Comment: why did you give me -1 :" , yeah it's only called on Editor, and my feature also only called on the editor. :)) , but thanks for the answer

Comment: I didn't ;) I just left my comments here